# Angular and Ionic Camera function wont save photo

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an app to take photos and upload them when the user synchronises their app. However, it keeps giving me errors after I take the photo and doesnt save it at all to phone.
Here is my code:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'camera';

angular.module('app').service(serviceId, ['$cordovaCamera', '$cordovaFile', '$q', function ($cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile, $q) {
    this.takePhoto = function () {

        if (window.Camera) {
            var options = {
                quality: 75,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 800,
                targetHeight: 800,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
                correctOrientation: true
            };

            return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                console.log("Photo Success: " + imageData);
                return imageData;
            }, function (err) {
                console.error("Error taking photo: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                throw err;
            });
        } else {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve("/img/sunrise.jpg");
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

}]);
})();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what error you are getting in console?

Comment: Error taking photo: "Error capturing image."(anonymous function) @ camera.js:26

Comment: camera.js is the code I posted above

Comment: Could you try `navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess,onFail,options);` instead of `$cordovaCamera.getPicture`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that you include the Camera and File plugins in your project.If not please add this two plugins,

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

and

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

I have made small example for you.Here I am using Ionic’s ngCordova to implement the Camera functionality,.

**Conroller**

```
$scope.photoSave = function() {
    if (window.cordova) {
        var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            cameraDirection: 1,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) {
            $scope.imgURI = imagePath;
            //Grab the file name of the photo in the temporary directory
            var currentName = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
            //Create a new name for the photo
            var d = new Date(),
                n = d.getTime(),
                newFileName = n + ".jpg";
            //Move the file to permanent storage
            $cordovaFile.moveFile(cordova.file.tempDirectory, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success) {
                //success.nativeURL will contain the path to the photo in permanent storage, do whatever you wish with it, e.g:
                //createPhoto(success.nativeURL);

            }, function(error) {
                //an error occured
            });

        }, function(error) {
            //An error occured
        });
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <button ng-click="photoSave()">Capture</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[**Refer**](http://www.joshmorony.com/store-camera-photos-permanently-using-phonegap-ionic-ngcordova/)

Comment: @Jeslabbert:Always welocme